# Python not reading\writing in 2nd file in for loop

Tags: python

Im trying to read two files and print them in another two separate files after reading and making some updates. My input file names are big-1.csv and big-2.csv. Therefore Im trying to read these two files using a for loop. For the output im trying to print them with names fix-1.csv and fix-2.csv but it seems my for loop is not running for the second time and only running once, while only reading and writing the first big-1.csv file to fix-1.csv file.

My code is :

```
import csv
from csv import DictWriter

for i in range(1,2):    
        print(i) #just a flag to check
        with open("big-" + str(i) + ".csv") as people_file:
            next(people_file)
            corrected_people = []
            for person_line in people_file:
                chomped_person_line = person_line.rstrip()
                person_tokens = chomped_person_line.split(",")

                # check that each field has the expected type
                try:
                    corrected_person = {
                    "id": person_tokens[0],
                    "first_name":person_tokens[1],
                    "last_name": "".join(person_tokens[2:-3]),
                    "email":person_tokens[-3],
                    "gender":person_tokens[-2],
                    "ip_address":person_tokens[-1]  

                    }

                    if not corrected_person["ip_address"].startswith(
                            "") and corrected_person["ip_address"] !="n/a":
                        raise ValueError

                    corrected_people.append(corrected_person)
                except (IndexError, ValueError):
                    # print the ignored lines, so manual correction can be performed later.
                    print("Could not parse line: " + chomped_person_line)

        with open("fix-" + str(i) + ".csv", "w") as corrected_people_file:
            writer = DictWriter(
            corrected_people_file,
            fieldnames=[
                        "id","first_name","last_name","email","gender","ip_address"
                ],delimiter=',')
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(corrected_people)
```

Th output im getting is :

```
j:\Programs\Python>python "for loop testing.py"
1

j:\Programs\Python>
```

And fix-1.csv file. The update part is working fine. The only problem I'm facing is that the for loop is running once. Please note, no indentation error is coming. Please help.

Comment: `range(1,2)` only contains one value (the number 1). Perhaps you meant `for i in (1,2):`

Comment: Oh thanks, that was the problem !!!

Comment: or `for i in range(1,3)` which will have 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

`range(1,2)` only contains one value (the number 1).

Perhaps you meant

```
for i in (1,2): # values are 1 and 2
```

or

```
for i in range(2): # values are 0 and 1
```

or

```
for i in range(1,3): # values are 1 and 2
```